# If $t_n\to t_0$ and $x(t_n)\to x_0$, does it follow $x(t_0)=x_0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, continuity

Let $E$ be a topological space, $(t_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq[0,\infty)$ be nondecreasing, $t_0\ge0$ with $t_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}t_0$ and $x:[0,\infty)\to E$ be càdlàg with $x(t_n)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}x_0$ for some $x_0\in E$.

Does it necessarily hold $x(t_0)=x_0$?

I can't prove this claim, but I've also fail to find a suitable counterexample.

Comment: Have you ever come accross the notion of one sided continuity ?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I've assumed that $x$ is càdlàg; i.e. right-continuous with left limits.

Comment: For the cadlag case, your result follows for **nonincreasing** sequences, not nondecreasing.

Comment: Then it should be not challenging to find a function which is cadlag and not left continuous, i.e having a jump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $t_n=1-\frac1n$, and $$x(t)=\begin{cases}0,&\ t<1\\[0.3cm] 1,&\ t≥1\end{cases}$$

Then $x(t_n)\to0$, while $x(1)=1$.

Comment: Your $t_n$ is not nondecreasing; it is nonincreasing.

Comment: You are right. How about now?